# Executing shell command through HTTPServer - command works only for duration of the request

Tags: python

Why does `subprocess.call("xdotool key XF86AudioPlay")` in `do_GET` only last for the duration of my http request?

I am trying to play/pause spotify on my local machine, through an http request. ie. when a request is received, emulate a keypress.

When I hit `localhost:8002` - the music plays for ~200ms, but as soon as the request finishes, it stops.

```
import http.server
import socketserver
import subprocess

MYCMD = "xdotool key XF86AudioPlay"
PORT = 8002

class MyRequestHandler(http.server.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        # Send the html message
        subprocess.call(MYCMD, shell=True)
        self.wfile.write(b'works')

        return

Handler = MyRequestHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dos not really make sense.

Normally subprocess.call() waits for the process to be called to be finished.

in your example it just simulates pressing a key on the server's xwindows.
you simulate pressing a key, that toggles playing audio.

What I would expect is, that somehow you perform two http requests.
The first one starting audio, the second one stopping audio.

Probably the two requests are executed with a delay of about 20ms.

What I propose is to add following lines before the subprocess call

```
with open("/tmp/mylogfile.log", "a") as fout:
    fout.write("call subprocess")
```

and following two lines after the subprocess call.

```
with open("/tmp/mylogfile.log", "a") as fout:
    fout.write("called subprocess")
```

I am quite sure, that you will see two instead of one request.

Comment: You're correct, I see two. Also, I hit the endpoint using chrome dev tools & checked the network tab. It only showed one request... Weird...

I swapped to flask and everything is working as intended.